# TextBoxes with TextChange which depend on each other without StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have Two Textboxes which depend on each other on their changes::
Assume: ::IF TextBox1 values changed makes impact to TextBox2 values, and viceversa is true::
Need: When I change TextBox1, i would like to have immediately result on            TextBox2

::IF TextBox1 values changed makes impact to TextBox2 values, and viceversa is true::

Example::
CalculatorView.xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Text={Binding Number1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<TextBox x:Name="TextBox2"  Text={Binding Number2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the backing field of the other property and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for it, e.g.:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _number1;
    public int Number1
    {
        get { return _number1; }
        set
        {
            _number1 = value;
            _number2 = 0; //sets the other property to any value...
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Number2));
        }
    }

    private int _number2;
    public int Number2
    {
        get { return _number2; }
        set
        {
            _number2 = value;
            _number1 = 0; //sets the other property to any value...
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Number1));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```